# AppCode Extract Function Issues

Tags: c++, refactoring, appcode, extract-method

I'm a student and have obtained a year free subscription to AppCode (via their student policies).  I downloaded it to use it in conjunction with Xcode, to refactor C++ code.  I'm noticing issues with the extract function feature.  I've tried it a handful of times, but I almost always get errors.  My initial thought was that it would automatically recognize that the selected code has variables, and introduce them in the function as parameters, but this didn't happen.  I have to manually enter them in, or else the function is inserted and errors occur.  After a handful of attempts, I had one situation where it DID recognize variables and created the function perfectly, entirely on its own.  Does anyone have any experience with AppCode and have any information on why it seems to randomly extract functions correctly only on a rare occasion without any help?  I dont entirely mind doing it manually, but at that point, it sort of defeats the purpose of even having a function extraction tool, as I can just do it all manually.

Comment: Could you please give us an example of non-working code with some sample project attached to the ticket in our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC?

Comment: Ill fill out a ticket today.  I love Appcode for the refactoring it offers that has worked.  In Xcode, I can't refactor variables and functions across multiple files, but AppCode did this perfectly fine for me.  I refactored hundreds of instances of various variables across 18-20 files took me about a half an hour.  Its excellent, but I couldn't get the function extraction to work.  There were instances where it didn't detect input and reference parameters and times it tried to return something after I explicitly changed the return type to void.  I'll put in an official ticket today.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your student policies, AppCode has been great for refactoring in every other aspect.  I'm thinking I'll end up purchasing it after I'm out of school, to use with Xcode.

Comment: @StanislavDombrovsky, done.  Thanks!  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14390#u=1477547450077